# How to know that IE tab (window) with ActiveX( COM ) control was closed?

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, com, activex

I have ActiveX ( COM ) control implented in C# that used in Internet Explorer. My control uses unmanaged resourses and I need know when tab(window) with control will be closed to release resources. 
How my control can know that IE tab (window) with ActiveX( COM ) control was closed (without javascript call control methods when window closed)?

Comment: possible duplicate What is the proper way for an activeX (COM) control to clean up when closed by its parent? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390571/what-is-the-proper-way-for-an-activex-com-control-to-clean-up-when-closed-by-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writing a `UserControl` override `OnHandleDestroyed` and place your resource releasing code there.
Don't forget to call `base.OnHandleDestroyed` after your code in that method.

Answer (score 0):

An ActiveX control is based on COM, which uses refcounting. Your control should dispose its resources when it's refcount goes to zero. This is not trivial to detect from a C# activex control, but according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223147/is-it-possible-to-intercept-or-be-aware-of-com-reference-counting-on-clr-object)'s answer, it is doable.